# Seemingly intractable combinatorial problem - find the set of rotate operations in a map

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

I just found a puzzle that kept me wondering. The prompt:

Given a map `M` composed of `N*N` tiles (N can be as large as 1000), consider an operation `R` such that `R{x,y,t}` rotates a tile from M, at coordinates `[x,y]`, `t` times - a 90 degree clockwise rotation.

Calculate the set of `R` operations that produce a map containing no cycles and no dangling tiles (for each tile, it links to its neighbours in at least one edge).

As a example:
Input:

```
┛┃╻┗╺╺┏╻
┣╹╺╋┫┓┃╹
┏┏┓┏━╻━━
╹┳┳╻╹━┣┛
━╻┻┣╻┳┣╺
┏┓┃┓┫┻╹╺
┗┳┳┓┛╋┓━
╻┗┓╺╸┗━┏
```

Can be rearranged to:

```
┏━╸┏╸╻┏╸
┣╸╺╋┳┛┃╻
┗┓┏┛┃╻┃┃
╻┣┫╻╹┃┣┛
┃╹┣┫╻┣┻╸
┗┓┃┗┻┫╻╻
┏┫┣┓┏╋┛┃
╹┗┛╹╹┗━┛
```

Which is a modified map that doesn't contain cycles nor dangling pieces.

The set of possible tiles includes:

```
"╸" and rotations: "╺", "╻", "╹"

"━" and rotation: "┃"

"┓" and rotations: "┛", "┏", "┗"

"┣" and rotations: "┳", "┻", "┫"

"╋"
```

Of course the brute-force solution (rotate every piece, check for correctness) is not viable, as the map can be big.

Every solution I can think of (graph with spanning tree, DP, even a genetic algorithm, recursive backtracking - can we even prune anything?) turns out to be as inefficient as the brute-force one. If the set is unique, does that change anything?

Best,

Comment: "no dangling tiles" reduces the search space a lot. So even a brute-force approach should eliminate a lot of cases quite early.

Comment: What does "rotate tile t times" mean?  Perhaps rotate tile through t times 90 degrees clockwise?  What about dangling?  Perhaps something like  each black tile edge is touching at leat one adjacent tile's black edge?  Is this a representation of some physical system, or just an abstract idea?

Comment: Hey @ravenspoint I'll edit to add your suggestions. This is an abstract idea.

Comment: One attempt would be SAT-solving. If i interpret this task correctly, then with some preprocessing of each tiles 4-neighborhood, the whole problem without *acyclicity* can be coloring-like described as: `tile x,y,o -> neighbor-tile-config_0 || neighbor-tile-config_1, ...` where neighbor-tile-config is another (a-priori deduced neighboring) tile whose selected orientation makes `tile x,y,o` non-dangling + `exactly_one(tile x,y,{o})` for each tile. *Acyclicity* is harder (see `SAT modulo Graphs: Acyclicity
(Gebser et al.`). Will it work for `N=1000`, maybe. It will (imho) beat brute-force.